# jQuery alertnative to 'Timeframe' (date range picker)

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-range

I'm trying to find a date ranger picker for jQuery.

First I found the [jQuery Tools solution](http://flowplayer.org/tools/dateinput/index.html) which looked absolutely perfect, but unfortunately does not work in IE6 which is by far the most commonly used browser here.

Then I found a [good range picker in jQuery](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/#about), but it seems quite limited as to what it returns in Javascript (I want both the start date, end date, and a calculation of the days between).

My attention then turned to [Timeframe](http://stephencelis.github.com/timeframe/), which once styled looked a perfect solution, allowing you to clearly see that it's a date picker, and also allowing you to click and drag between dates. The problem; it uses prototype, which I'm not allowed to use here (jQuery or plain JavaScript only!)

If anyone knows of any solutions that meet my needs I'd really appreciate it, thank you.

ps. I tried the [default jQuery date range picker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) but found it to be very clunky, bloated and not to my needs unfortunately.

Comment: I have exactly the same need, and followed the same steps. Timeframe has a good user interface for selecting a range (certainly the most intuitive), but I also need to use jQuery, not Prototype.

Comment: Another one that I have used -- but it not perfect, but should be listed here is: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Answer (score 4):

An old question but for arrivals from google... another alternative is <s>http://reaktor.github.com/jquery-continuous-calendar/src/example.html</s>  http://reaktor.github.com/jquery-continuous-calendar/

it allows easy drag hilighting across many months (via a scroll) and is JQuery based.
HTH

Note to OP, this plugin doesn't work in IE6.

Comment: @microspino Thanks for the heads up, i think this is the correct version

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear from your question, but have you looked at JQueryUI and the datepicker in there?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Many thanks for the recommendation, but this is the 'default jQuery date range picker' I mentioned in the first post that I really didn't get on with, ideally I'd like something that makes it more intuitive as a date picker (click the first date, then the last, or drag like Timeline) and preferably also something that'll calculate the days between the two dates too.